# Adding resource files to targets is not working on Xcode 9

Tags: xcode9

When I drag .png files to my project and check the targets in "Add to targets" section, these files are added to the project but not to the targets.

Then I have to select target membership for these files manually.

Source files (.cpp) are added normally.

This just happens on Xcode 9. Previous versions work fine.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, all my new .png images were not showing with Xcode 9. I manually added them to the target as you describe and they show fine now.

Comment: The same problem. Not only with .png, with .m too. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is XCode 9 bug.
I have the same problem not only with .png, with .m files too.

Opened Radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/33577678

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have checkbox `create groups` selected and not `create folder references` while you adding files to project. It fixed target issue with adding group of files for me.
[image]